# Kali linux не загружается после обновления

Tags: linux, dfs

на live usb создал раздел persistent , обновился до актуальной версии kali и словил проблему при загрузке с модулем wifi. как решить?

пишет:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а в чём проблема-то?

Comment: Виснет не то, что последнее отобразилось на экране (отображается как раз то, что работает). Виснет то, что должно быть после этого. Надо поискать, что же должно отобразиться дальше.

Comment: @Arhad, с большой вероятностью — просто ожидание получения сетевой конфигурации, и надо всего лишь подождать.

Comment: дальше не идет, минут 5 ждал. @Arhad а где поискать?

Comment: Есть подозрение, что дальше идёт инициализация графики. Попробуйте загрузиться в «безопасном» режиме (игнорирует X.Org в довесок к некоторым другим изменениям). Для этого: 1) зажмите *Shift* во время загрузки (но до загрузки самого Linux), чтобы войти в меню загрузчика; 2) перейдите в пункт «Advanced Options...»; 3) перейдите в пункт «... (recovery mode)». Если загрузка пройдёт успешно (появилось предложение ввести имя пользователя), значит проблема действительно в видеодрайвере.

Comment: @Arhad ок спасибо. на live usb не работает шифт. переустановил раздел persistent все заработало. в прошлый раз видимо после обновления какого то пакета вроде видеодрайвера перестала загружаться система